# Newly started using Botium,working on the sample provided on GitHub for utterance, Not working

Tags: chatbot

working on Botium samples provided in your site. utterance sample, while running giving error.

```
C:\Botium\botium-bindings-master\samples\utterances\node_modules\mocha\node_modu
les\yargs\yargs.js:1163
      else throw err
           ^

ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined
```

Comment: Can we see the code that throws the error?

Answer (score 1):

The sample in question is not for mocha, but tailored to the [jest test runner](https://jestjs.io/).
It is actually very easy, just run:

```
npm install
npm test
```

*Please note that for this sample to work, you will have to download another Git repository: Download botium-utterances package from https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-utterances and unpack it to ./spec/convo/botium-utterances-master.*